# Powershell get-adcomputer + wmi query in one shot

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a query that is listing all computers and their OS, and exporting it to a CSV file:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter{OperatingSystem -NotLike "*server*"} -Properties * | select name,CanonicalName,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | Export-Csv C:\Temp\AllComputersOS.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I would like to also know the chassistype, and have this `WMI` query:

```
WmiObject win32_systemenclosure -computer $computer.Name | Select chassistypes
```

How can I combine these two commands and export the results to a single csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this via a calculated property in the `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*server*"} -Properties * | select name,CanonicalName,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,@{N='ChassisType';E={(WmiObject win32_systemenclosure -ComputerName $_.Name).chassistypes}} | Export-Csv C:\Temp\AllComputersOS.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Beware this will be fairly slow to execute.

The calculated property part is this:

```
@{N='ChassisType';E={(WmiObject win32_systemenclosure -ComputerName $_.Name).chassistypes}}
```

It uses a special hashtable construct where you provide the keys `N` (Name, although you can also use `L` for Label or either in full) and `E` (Expression) to, where the Expression is some scriptblock to execute. Within this we're using `$_.Name` to get the current computer name property from the pipeline variable.

Comment: Perfect!! Many thanks. Sure I am aware that the WMI part is slowing this one down significantly. But great response and explanation!! Cheers

Comment: No problem, FYI you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the tick under the voting buttons.